# Google apps multiple domains with multiple email accounts

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

If I sign up for google apps with `example.com` can I then create multiple email accounts on my domain like `email1@example.com` `email2@example.com` with no additional costs?

Is it possible then to add my another domain `example.net` to my account and setup multiple email accounts same way like `email1example.net` `email2@example.net`? How many domains and multiple related email accounts I can add this way?

Is it all possible without additional costs involved?

Answer (score 4):

With Google Apps, you pay per account.  So if you have 3 accounts you will pay for 3.  Each account has it's own email address.  However you can add an alias to an account.  So `email1@mydomain.com` will be the primary account email address and you can have `email2@mydomain.com` as an alias where any emails sent to `email2@mydomain.com` will go to the Gmail of `email1@mydomain.com`.

If you want to have separate Gmail accounts for `email1` and `email2` you will have to pay for two accounts.  Just note that each account come with their own Google Drive space and access to all the Google Apps Suite.

**Domains**

You can have multiple domains within the same Google Apps account in two different ways.  Make sure you check out the [limitations on multiple domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081)

**1. Domain Alias**

This will give each user in your current Google Apps an alternate email address with the secondary domain name -- No extra cost.

**2. Additional Domain**

This will be a new set of users added under the second domain name.  Each user will have their own account and you pay per account.

**More Info / Training - Google Apps Certified Administrator**

I would highly recommend doing this training if you are going to be managing a Google Apps account, even a small one.  The training material is free from Google and you can take the test ($100) at the end if you would like to have the certification on your resume or whatever.  It explains the type of question you just asked very clearly and a everything else about Google Apps.

Comment: In case of Domain Alias will each user have separate email account? Can I have `email1@domain2.com` `email1@domain3.com` separate email boxes?

Comment: In that case it will be the same mailbox. You can choose to 'Send As' each of the emails addresses however.

Comment: OK I see but If I want to give an access to someone to `email3@domain3.com` email will be they able to access emails on these address?

Comment: Access is only gained from the primary email address, once logged in the user will have access to emails from all alias's associated with that account.  You cannot create access rules on alias's

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify if you need each account to be unique logins. But in short there is a way to funnel multiple emails/domains/aliases into a single inbox and then use filters to parse out the results if your requirements are:
- multiple email addresses/aliases
- multiple email domains
- single login
- no additional cost

If your requirements need separate logins for each email then there will be a cost for each physical account.

I have 3 domain aliases tied to my google apps for business account and I pay for one physical account.  From within this one physical account I can add unlimited aliases inside of google apps and then inside of gmail I create filters so that any email from "alias1@domainA.com" will auto tag themselves as alias1@domainA. I also setup send as for these email aliases so that when I reply it defaults to from the original email. I also setup separate email signatures for each.

Using this setup I currently have 7 emails flowing into my Google Apps and all separate themselves automatically via filter rules.